# Iphone Phonebook in my application

Tags: iphone, ios4

I have application that send sms. I have texfield for nuber of receiver. I want to add button and when this button is clicked user phonebook to appear and select number from contact list. This number should appear in text field. How can I do that?

Best regards,
Nikolay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leverage stuff out of the AddressBook framework, including existing view controllers.

See http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AddressBookUI/Reference/AddressBookUI_Framework/_index.html